# Asset Pipeline Cacheing CSS?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-3.1, sass, asset-pipeline

I am working on a Rails 3.1 app. I have created an `application.css.scss.erb` file. The .erb is in the end because I want to load a variable from the config file as the color variable in the css:

```
$highlight1: #<%= COLOR.highlight1 %>;
$highlight2: #<%= COLOR.highlight2 %>;
```

Everything works fine, but the problem I am having is that whenever I change a value inside COLOR.highlight1, it doesn't reflect the change until I go in to my css file and change something (i usually add some spaces and save it). Thats when I see the change. Clearly rails is looking to see if the file was changed in order to update the change.

Is there any way that at least during development, this can be turned off and I can see the changes without having to also modify the css file?

Any critique/opinions on my technique are also welcome

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to store this in a constant?

Comment: Actually, I needed to include Twitter Bootstrap which needs LESS. So long story short, I wanted a single place where I would declare the color and then use that color in declaring values in SASS (which is what my application uses throughout) and a little bit of LESS (which is what Twitter Bootstrap works on). Makes sense?

Comment: You try using guard to watch your ruby file and force an update on the sass - http://railscasts.com/episodes/264-guard

Answer (score 7):

The Sprockets `depend_on` directive is used to declare these kinds of dependencies.  So at the top of your css.scss.erb file, with the other directives (require and friends), put something like:

```
//= depend_on "/path/to/colors.rb"
```

Then when the file `/path/to/colors.rb` changes, it will force the css to update too.

Unfortunately, I have never gotten this to work with a relative path to a file *outside* of one of the asset directories (javascripts/stylesheets/images) so there may be something in the way Sprockets resolves paths that prevents this, or else I'm missing something.  That leaves you with the options of specifying an absolute path, which will almost certainly not work in across all your app environments, or putting the constants file into your asset directories (app/assets/stylesheets/colors.rb, for example).

For reference, here's the doc for the `depend_on` directive from the Sprockets (2.0.3) source, in sprockets/directive_processor.rb

```
  # Allows you to state a dependency on a file without
  # including it.
  #
  # This is used for caching purposes. Any changes made to
  # the dependency file will invalidate the cache of the
  # source file.
  #
  # This is useful if you are using ERB and File.read to pull
  # in contents from another file.
  #
  #     //= depend_on "foo.png"
  #
```

If anyone does know a way to specify relative paths to other places like config/initializers or something, please let me know!

Comment: See [the answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10596268/235855) if you want to use relative paths.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to David Faber's answer. I needed to use relative paths too.

I wanted to generate a js file with the locale dictionary, which would update if the locale files were changed:

```
//= depend_on "../../../config/locales/en.yml"
//= depend_on "../../../config/locales/ja.yml"

var locales = <%= locales.to_json %>;
```

Turns out that currently (Rails 3.2.3) relative paths only work if the relative path is also in the assets path!

So the ugly solution is to add the path in `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.paths.unshift Rails.root.join("config", "locales").to_s
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try:

```
config.assets.digest = true
```

in your development config file

Answer (score 0):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html

> - config.assets.compile is a boolean that can be used to turn on live Sprockets compilation in production.

might want to try that, I'm not sure if its getting compiled real time though, at least it should disable the caching.

Answer (score 0):

I try this, it work

in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W(#{config.root}/lib/assets_variables)
config.assets.paths << File.join(Rails.root, 'lib', 'assets_variables')
```

in lib/assets_variables/color.rb

```
module Color
  def self.default
    'blue'
  end
end
```

in app/assets/stylesheets/color.css.scss.erb

```
//= depend_on "color.rb"
$default_color: <%= Color::default %>;
.content {
  color: $default_color;
}
```